# Checking a word starts with specific alphabets python

Tags: python

I have a string test_file1. I want to check taking a string from user if the string he/she enters starts with 'test'. How to do this in python? 
let args be =['test_file']

```
for suite in args:
            if suite.startswith('test'):
                suite="hello.tests."+suite
            print(suite) // prints hello.tests.test_file
print(args) //prints ['test.file]' and not ['hello.tests.test_file']
```

Comment: It should work, Also, please see [MCVE]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: why startswith won't work?? can you explain

Comment: Well, I am changing a string in a list and its modified, startswith works but then the final list shows no change in the string. I made the edit in question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
String.startswith(str, beg=0,end=len(string))
```

In your case, it'll be

```
word.startswith('test', 0, 4)
```

Comment: Are `beg` and `end` required in this case?

Comment: Thanx! I didn't know those params. But should be `str.startswith` and not `String.startswith`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the regex.

```
pat = re.compile(r'^test.*')
```

then you can use this pattern for checking each line.

Comment: A dot `.` should be placed before `*`

Answer (score 0):

Problem with code is you are not replacing the suite in args list with new created suite name .

**Check this out**

```
args = ['test_file']
print "Before args are -",args
for suite in args:
    #Checks test word
    if suite.startswith('test'):
        #If yes, append "hello.tests"
        new_suite="hello.tests."+suite
        #Replace it in args list
        args[args.index(suite)]=new_suite

print "After args are -",args
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
Before args are - ['test_file']
After args are - ['hello.tests.test_file']

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

Above can be also implemented using **list comprehension.**

```
args = ['test_file',"file_test"]
print "Before args are -",args

args = ["hello.tests."+suite if suite.startswith('test') else suite for suite in args]

print "After args are -",args
```